# Mac Catalyst swipe-to-delete not working on Mac

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mac-catalyst

Swipe to delete not working in `maccatalyst`. The same code working fine with iPad.

the `UITableview` `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` method not called in `maccatalyst`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool
{
 
    if indexPath.row == RestrictedDeletionRoom
    {
        return false
    }
    else
    {
        return true
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    
    let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, sourceView, completionHandler) in
        
        self.deletedRowDict = self.RoomsListArray.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
        
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? RoomsListCellTableViewCell {
            let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let popoverContent = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tableViewCellPopUp") as! tableViewCellPopUp
            popoverContent.delegate = self
            popoverContent.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
            popoverContent.view.superview?.layer.cornerRadius = 1
            popoverContent.msgTxt?.text = "Are you sure you want to delete this Room?"
            
            if let popover = popoverContent.popoverPresentationController {
                
                let viewForSource = cell.deleteView
                popover.sourceView = viewForSource
                popover.permittedArrowDirections = .left
                // the position of the popover where it's showed
                popover.sourceRect = (viewForSource?.bounds)!
                
                popoverContent.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width:400,height:65)//
            }
            self.present(popoverContent, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        completionHandler(false)
    }
    
    let swipeAction = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete])
    swipeAction.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
    return swipeAction
}
```

Has anyone solved this one?

Comment: I ran into this as well and did not solve it. Just wondering: would it be possible to add a Control-click (Right-click) menu in the Mac Catalyst version of iOS apps?

Comment: To answer my own question. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontextmenuinteraction

Answer (score 9):

Are you trying using a mouse down swipe or a scroll swipe via an Apple mouse scroll gesture - horizontal swipe gesture on the mouse? Swipes generally need the mouse swipe gesture, not mouse down on Mac Catalyst

Comment: Swipe-to-delete is a built-in feature of UITableViewController, enabled by implementing a method of the UITableViewDataSource delegate.  `".. you must implement the tableView(_:commit:forRowAt:) method to enable the swipe-to-delete feature for rows."`  It works fine in iOS, but is not working in Mac Catalyst.

Comment: 's answer is correct.  Swipe-to-delete works correctly on Mac Catalyst if you do a scroll swipe on the Apple mouse (two-fingered swipe if using trackpad) instead of Click & Drag.

Comment: What if a user does not use an Apple mouse?