# Swipe-to-delete does not work using mouse on Mac in iPad app

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, ipad

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        if (![self.info rightGranted:self.user_app_id :4 :self.rights_list])
        {
            [General showAlert:NSLocalizedString(@"no_delete_rights", @"") :NSLocalizedString(@"do_not_have_delete_rights", @"") :NSLocalizedString(@"ok", @"") :self];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            return;
        }
        
        [General promptAbandonChanges:self :NSSelectorFromString(@"deleteUserConfirm2:") :NSLocalizedString(@"confirm_delete_user", @"") :NSLocalizedString(@"delete_user_alert", @"") :self :(NSObject *)indexPath];
    }
}
```

iOS apps created for My Mac (Designed for iPad) do not call this delegate function when simulating a swipe gesture with an external mouse on my mac.

Has anybody figured this out yet? Swipe gesture works with the mouse for almost everything else but not swiping to delete. Is there a more preferred delegate function?

Comment: I feel like this is probably by design - there are so many more instances in the day-to-day use of a trackpad where you may swipe a certain direction to move the cursor that would inadvertently trigger this gesture, whereas on mobile devices the swipe gesture really isn’t too terribly common otherwise and can be contextualized with where the touch began and ended to ultimately make a much more accurate determination of the user’s intent than in a non-mobile environment.

Comment: I reported this issue with the Feedback Assistant. The delegate method is not called in Objective C or Swift.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mac Catalyst swipe-to-delete not working on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895546/maccatalyst-swipe-to-delete-not-working-in-ios-13)

Comment: No, not Mac Catalyst. Not sure there is a name for it, but it is iOS running in an iPad window on a Mac.

Comment: The edit queue is full, but this is a "Designed for iPad|iPhone" (running on Apple Silicon), not Mac Catlyst, right? Can ask-er do direct edit?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work... but I don't have the exact setup you do.

I have a published iOS SDK app that is running on my M1, and the swipe works.

Here's details, in case its a very small differential:

1. iPhone-only (not universal, so runs as "Designed for iPhone"
2. written in swift.
3. the delete handler leverages the settings, there is no function that customizes it.
4. In contrast, I do have the modern swipe-left handler implemented, and it works too.

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
       leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt
       indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
   ```

There's two areas of concern I'd have:

1. If use use the old (right-swipe-only) method that was deprecated.
2. The tableview behavior seems to live in AppKit. I am working on other table features that crash inside AppKit, that might be using the `NSTables` or be shimmed on top(?)